# Node for a basic Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I've been given my first client website to build. It's to be very basic with home/about/our services/contact. My question, as a newbie, is whether I should be using Node/Express or any other frameworks for something so basic, or is it possible to do a decent job without them (since the layout will be so simple)?

There are so many frameworks etc that I know could be used so it all gets confusing. At this stage in my career I'd really just like to focus on improving with Vanilla JS/jQuery if possible but I still want to make a nice looking site.

Comment: Server side code, let alone something that requires specialist hosting like Node, seems unnecessary for the problem you describe.

Comment: Don't use node.js, the features you listed do not need a server app, just go with something really simple using bootstrap or whatever quick way you're comfortable with to deliver a first working product and get some feedback.
I would also stay as far as I could from using angular / react / whatever, it doesn't seem to be necessary either.

Comment: Great, thank you both - I'll keep it simple and not go down any backend/angular/react etc rabbitholes on this occasion :-)

Comment: You sound like you need to build a static website. You will need neither clientside nor serverside scripting for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make a pure-network based website that has a server and a client-side you should definitely go for Node.js. Otherwise make sure you get as much experience as you can in JavaScript, jQuery and Bootstrap for having a strong base as a newbie web-developer.